# Increase double-click cursor movement sensitivity

Tags: macos, mouse, trackpad

(Note: I think this is new in Yosemite, as I never had this problem before updating, but it's possible I just never noticed.)

In Accessibility preferences (formerly Mouse/Trackpad), it is possible to set how much time delay can occur between the two components of a double-click.

It seems OS X also allows a certain amount of cursor movement in this interval (~15 pixels, I think), and I would like to decrease the allowance to about 2 pixels.

Why? I am fairly fast with the mouse, and even at the minimum delay time, sometimes when rapidly clicking several things in a list OS X thinks I'm double-clicking on one item and opens it instead.

If you haven't experienced this, try increasing the delay in Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad and clicking on two adjacent items in the Finder.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with distance, just duration between clicks.

Comment: @user14492 No, distance is definitely a relevant variable. To prove this, decrease the necessary speed in Accessibility, click, move the mouse more than 15 pixels, and click again. That will not register as a double-click. However, if you only move the mouse ~10 pixels, it will register, even if it is done at exactly the same speed.